# Flash/Javascript upload in spite of same origin policy

Tags: javascript, flash, file-upload, uploadify, same-origin-policy

Can one upload files to a domain other than the domain a script originates from?

For example, suppose you're hosting files on `www.example.com`, and you want to upload files to `uploads.example.com`, would the following script violate the same origin policy (using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)):

```
<!-- from http://www.example.com/upload.html -->
<input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fileInput').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'http://upload.example.com/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
    'auto'      : true,
    'folder'    : '/uploads'
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

I haven't seen a clear reference on the same origin policy that would indicate one-way or the other whether the this would be an issue with any browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Flash expert, but I think you would need to set up a `crossdomain.xml` file for that as described [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html).